# Gson deserialize Object with Map inside

Tags: java, android, json, gson, deserialization

I have a simple JSON:

> {"localization":[{"app.home":"Home","app.menu":"Menu"}]}

I created it's Java representation:

```
public class Config {
    @Key("localization")
    private Map<String, String> mLocalization = new HashMap<String, String>();
    public Map<String, String> getLocalization() {
        return mLocalization;
    }

    public void setLocalization(Map<String, String> mLocalization) {
        this.mLocalization = mLocalization;
    }
}
```

@Key is because I use it within Robospice.
When I'm trying to parse it I receive an exception:

> 12-11 15:27:24.104: W/System.err(8133): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key localization, field private java.util.Map com.example.gson.Config.mLocalization
>   12-11 15:27:24.104: W/System.err(8133): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected collection or array type but got java.util.Map

So how can I parse it? I don't want to parse it to array and then fill `Map` by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you have array of maps in your JSON instead of map, should be:

```
{"localization": {"app.home":"Home","app.menu":"Menu"}}
```

Or you can declare your key as an array of maps:

```
private Map<String, String>[] mLocalization;
```

Comment: Yeah, didn't notice that.